# Calculate average time from array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, datetime, hash, average

I am trying to calculate the average time from an array of hashes.  Here's the array.

```
array = [
  {"startTime"=>"2015-12-05T07:49:30.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-05T15:56:30.000Z"},
  {"startTime"=>"2015-12-04T07:02:30.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-04T14:59:30.000Z"},
  {"id"=>"5660614e8a3b090700bad845", "userId"=>"55cd59542d98600100397c12", "day"=>"2015-12-03", "startTime"=>"2015-12-03T06:02:32.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-03T13:38:32.000Z"},
  {"startTime"=>"2015-12-02T09:17:33.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-02T15:27:33.000Z"},
  {"startTime"=>"2015-12-01T05:45:36.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-01T13:50:36.000Z"}
]
```

I'm trying to get the average startTime and endTime.  Here is what I have tried so far.

```
avg = Time.at(array.map {|x| x['startTime']}.reduce(:+).to_f / array.size.to_i)
```

The result I get is 1969-12-31 16:06:43 -0800.  This is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'time'

array = [
  {"startTime"=>"2015-12-05T07:49:30.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-05T15:56:30.000Z"},
  {"startTime"=>"2015-12-04T07:02:30.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-04T14:59:30.000Z"},
  {"id"=>"5660614e8a3b090700bad845", "userId"=>"55cd59542d98600100397c12", "day"=>"2015-12-03", "startTime"=>"2015-12-03T06:02:32.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-03T13:38:32.000Z"},
  {"startTime"=>"2015-12-02T09:17:33.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-02T15:27:33.000Z"},
  {"startTime"=>"2015-12-01T05:45:36.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-01T13:50:36.000Z"}
]

times = array.map{|el| el['startTime']}.map{|el| Time.parse(el) }
#=> [2015-12-05 07:49:30 UTC, 2015-12-04 07:02:30 UTC, 2015-12-03 06:02:32 UTC, 2015-12-02 09:17:33 UTC, 2015-12-01 05:45:36 UTC]

average_time = Time.at(times.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / times.size)
#=> 2015-12-03 08:11:32 +0100
```

Comment: `el` should already be a string, so I don't think you need to call `#to_s` on it.

Comment: For some reason I'm not getting the right average time for this array.

times = [2015-12-10 05:58:24 UTC,
2015-12-09 03:35:28 UTC,
2015-12-08 06:32:26 UTC,
2015-12-07 01:43:28 UTC,
2015-12-05 07:49:30 UTC,
2015-12-04 07:02:30 UTC]

ave = Time.at(bed_times.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / bed_times.size)
2015-12-07 01:26:57 -0800

This is not the right average time.  Also, how would I convert this to a different Time Zone?

Comment: @user2974739 why is it not? I think that between 04 and 10 the average is somewhere at 07. So I assume it is right avg.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'

keys = ["startTime", "endTime"]
n = array.size
keys.zip(array.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys).map { |d| Time.parse(d).to_f }}.
     transpose.
     map { |a| Time.at(a.reduce(:+)/n) }).to_h
  #=> {"startTime"=>2015-12-02 23:11:32 -0800, "endTime"=>2015-12-03 06:46:32 -0800}
```

The steps:

```
keys = ["startTime", "endTime"]
n = array.size
  #=> 5
a = array.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys).map { |d| DateTime.parse(d).to_time.to_f }}
  #=> [[1449301770.0, 1449330990.0],
  #    [1449212550.0, 1449241170.0],
  #    [1449122552.0, 1449149912.0],
  #    [1449047853.0, 1449070053.0],
  #    [1448948736.0, 1448977836.0]]
```

In computing `a`, the block variable is initially set to the first element of `array`:

```
h = array.first
  #=> {"startTime"=>"2015-12-05T07:49:30.000Z", "endTime"=>"2015-12-05T15:56:30.000Z"}
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
b = h.values_at(*keys)    
  #=> ["2015-12-05T07:49:30.000Z", "2015-12-05T15:56:30.000Z"] 
b.map { |d| Time.parse(d).to_f }
  #=> [1449301770.0, 1449330990.0]
```

Other elements of `a` are calculated similarly.

Continuing with the calculation:

```
c = a.transpose
  #=> [[1449301770.0, 1449212550.0, 1449122552.0, 1449047853.0, 1448948736.0],
  #    [1449330990.0, 1449241170.0, 1449149912.0, 1449070053.0, 1448977836.0]] 

d = c.map { |a| Time.at(a.reduce(:+)/n) }
  #=> [2015-12-02 23:11:32 -0800, 2015-12-03 06:46:32 -0800]
```

The calculation of `d` is equivalent to:

```
e = c.map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }
  #=> [7245633461.0, 7245769961.0] 
f = e.map { |t| t/n }
  #=> [1449126692.2, 1449153992.2] 
d = f.map { |t| Time.at(t) }
  #=> [2015-12-02 23:11:32 -0800, 2015-12-03 06:46:32 -0800]
```

The last step is to present the result in a hash:

```
g = keys.zip(d)
  #=> [["startTime", 2015-12-02 23:11:32 -0800], ["endTime", 2015-12-03 06:46:32 -0800]] 
g.to_h
  #=> {"startTime"=>2015-12-02 23:11:32 -0800,
  #    "endTime"=>2015-12-03 06:46:32 -0800}
```